# Run Android services Until App Destroyed

Tags: android, service, timer

Actually i have to perform some technique in which some particular method will be called after specified time until app destroyed.I Google it and have found services.Using services this work can be performed.I have gone through many Service tutorials so now i can work with services but can anybody tell me how to do this. Should i use services for call particular tack in the background of the activity after specified time?...Thanks....

**Edit:** I have used following code

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimeTask);
        handler.postDelayed(updateTimeTask, 1000);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started................",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private Runnable updateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (count == 50) {
                count = 0;
                Tocken_parser tocken = new Tocken_parser();
                tocken.tockenParser("1");
                Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "coutn===", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                System.out.println("Count ===============");
            }
            count++;
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }

    };
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        System.out
                .println("Service destroyed........................................");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Its working properly but tell me one thing, how to stop services when activity destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is `YES`. Also, the `Service` that spawned by `Activity` will be destroyed together; unless, you assign a schedule check on `Alarm` to wake up your dead `Service`.

Comment: Thanks @xjaphx I have edited my question have look and please tell me how to stop Service.